# ParcelJS: Build HTML to different subdirectories using the same code

Tags: javascript, html, npm, parceljs

I have two .html files using the same Javascript code and assets. As they are representing different language versions of the same site, I would like to build them to different subdirectories with parcel.

Currently, I'm building these in an asymmetric way. The .html files are the entry points, `index.html` being the English language version:

*Current input:*

```
  |-*.css, *.js, ...
  |–index.html
  |-de.html
```

*Current output:*

```
dist
  |-*.css, *.js, ...
  |-index.html
  |-de.html
```

*Current build command*

```
parcel build --public-url . index.html de.html
```

However, I would like to have them in a more symmetric way:

*Desired input:*

```
  |-*.css, *.js, ...
  |–en
     |-index.html
  |-de
     |-index.html
```

*Desired output:*

```
dist
  |-*.css, *.js, ...
  |–en
    |- index.html
  |-de
    |- index.html
```

I'm wondering two things here:

- What would the build command need to look like?
- When changing the location of the files from `index.html` and `de.html` to `en/index.html` and `de/index.html`, do I have move up the relative links in the html files, e. g. from `<link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./example.css">` or is this automatically cared for by changing the build command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it myself using this example from a bug report [here](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/3540). As I want to preserve only the file structure of my entry points (the html files in my case), this can be achieved pretty easily.

For example, with the following *input*:

```
|- test.js
|- locales
   |- en
      |- index.html
   |- de
      |- index.html
```

I get the following *output*:

```
dist
|- test.js
|- en
   |- index.html
|- de
   |- index.html
```

Using this *command* in my `package.json`:

```
parcel build locales/**/*.html --public-url ../
```

To use `test.js` in one of the html files, it is necessary to go up two directories up with this structure:

```
<script src="../../test.js"></script>
```

Of course it's also possible to omit the subdirectory `locales`, then only `../` needs to be used in the script.

It seems to be not as easy if one wants to preserve the directory structure of non-entry points but for my case it turned out to be very easy.